# How to serve static images in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, nestjs

I'm started to learning MEAN stack and when I went to Express I saw that existed a extra layer in the express framework that is called NestJS. It had all what I wanted and it had an Angular-like syntax so was perfect to me.

But every new step is a nightmare documentation isn't usefull at all. Now I'm fighting with the framework to achieve to serve images and dont use the API for this kind of calls.

I tried all that I found on Internet, for example:

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';



declare const module: any;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));




  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });

//I tried this 2 options (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) (https://whatthecode.dev/serve-static-files-with-nest-js/)
  app.use('/resources', express.static(process.cwd() + '\\resources'));
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', '\\public'));

  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
 
  //console.log(process.cwd());


  await app.listen(3000);

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => app.close());
  }

}
bootstrap();
```

I tried to put it in the app.module as this (it worked but is always looking for an index.html not images):

```
import { AnimalsModule } from './animals/animals.module';
import { SpeciesModule } from './species/species.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { BreedModule } from './breed/breed.module';
import { StateModule } from './state/state.module';
import { PhotoModule } from './photo/photo.module';


@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),   // <-- path to the static files
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'nest',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    AnimalsModule,
    SpeciesModule,
    BreedModule,
    StateModule,
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    PhotoModule,
  ],
})

//It seems that ignores this register and just uses the method signature options
@Module({
  imports: [MulterModule.register({
    dest: './resources/tmp',
    limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, fileSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How the hell I can serve images or files and avoid the api routing?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Given such configuration (which seems okay), could you possibly share your static folder `public` directory structure and a simple GET which you've tried for some static asset?

Comment: Hi, I have this structure:

project/resources
               /tmp
               /files
project/public (just for try this name, because is more common to see in examples)


And my GET request is put in the browser http://localhost:3000/resources/a.jpg or public folder.

If you need other things say it to me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yet, you configure you rootPath as follows: `rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public')`?

Comment: Try to put your `a.jpg` into project/public and GET it via localhost:3000/a.jpg

Comment: rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public')? Is in the second file in the original question, and I tried this request and it returns a 404 route not found by firefox

Answer (score 26):

This is what I've done:

1. in app.module.ts

   ```
    import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static/dist/serve-static.module';
    import { join } from 'path';

    @Module({
        imports: [
            ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
                rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
            }),
        ],
    })
   ```
2. Then I created "public" dir on the same level as "src", "dir" etc.
3. The file is available at: https://my-url/file.jpg

Comment: i have done that but have this error "ENOENT: no such file or directory" it is show me file not find in \dist\public\index.html

Comment: Resolution for "no such file" error might be found here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/320
Supplementing compilerOptions.assets worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

Use the `useStaticAssets()` method (the `ServeStaticModule` is for serving static content like SPAs).
So as a minimal example, your `main.ts` should look like the following):

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

In the above example your assets are served from the root of your application (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/example.png`.

You can also pass options to the method in oder to configure the path from which the assets are served:

```
  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {
    prefix: '/public/',
  });
```

In this example your path is prefixed with `public` (e.g.  `http://localhost:3000/public/example.png`)

Comment: `import { join } from 'path';` and `import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';`

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to serve static content in `NestJs`. Either use `1` OR `2`.

1.Using `ServeStaticModule` in **app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';
import { mainModule } from 'process'    
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2.Using `NestExpressApplication` in **main.ts** [Even by default Nest Js uses Express only]

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 4):

you can move to root directory, if your upload folder is in rootdir then put the path of folder in renderPath like this.

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '../../'),
  renderPath: '/uploads',
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I also struggled with this issue for a very long time.
For example: you have uploads folder for picture.
In App.module you need use it:

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
}),
```

localhost:3000/picture.png

if i use without 'client' folder, my picture is

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '..'),
}),
```

localhost:3000/client/picture.png

Answer (score 1):

Separate module solution, then import it into AppModule.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { resolve } from 'path';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot(
            (() => {
                const publicDir = resolve('./public/files/');
                const servePath = '/files';

                return {
                    rootPath: publicDir,
                    // serveRoot - if you want to see files on another controller,
                    // e.g.: http://localhost:8088/files/1.png
                    serveRoot: servePath,
                    exclude: ['/api*'],
                };
            })()
        ),
    ],
})
export class PublicModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `app.module.ts`:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
      ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
        rootPath: join(__dirname, ".."),
        renderPath: "public",
      }),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*`rootPath` - Static files root directory. Default: "client"* 
*`renderPath` - Path to render static app (concatenated with the serveRoot value). Default: * (wildcard - all paths).* 
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/serve-static)

###### You should set `rootPath` to project root directory and `renderPath` to your static files.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/uploads/public'),
      serveStaticOptions: { index: false },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will serve images from /dist/uploads/public/

You can access the files or images from, http://localhost:3000/x.jpg

Answer (score 0):

add this to main.ts
replace "uploads" with your directory name
app.use('/uploads',express.static(join(process.cwd(), 'uploads')));

Comment: Can you please edit this and explain why? In that case this would also help other people finding this issue, as it is most likely that the original question asker already solved the issue after 10 months ;)

Comment: This works for me just for getting the static content. I can upload elements without this, but I can't see it

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @pzabrocki brings me to the following minimal working repository: https://gitlab.com/hadrien-toma/nest-static-files

To play with it:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/hadrien-toma/nest-static-files
yarn install
yarn run start
```

Then the `my-file.json` is served at `http://localhost:3333/my-file.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The main method of document nest using the module is as follows:

```
 ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
    rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'upload'),   //  path to the static files image
 }),
```

But if you get the error for searching the `index.html`, you can use this method, which I also used

main.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';

app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '../upload')))
```

Answer (score 0):

To serve static files, including images, in a NestJS application, you can use the `express.static` middleware provided by the Express framework, which is integrated into NestJS. Here's how you can set it up:

1. Create a folder in your project's directory to store your public images. For example, you can create a folder named `public` at the root level of your project.
2. Move your images into the `public` folder. You can organize them into subdirectories if necessary.
3. Open the `main.ts` (or `main.js`) file in the root directory of your NestJS application.
4. Import the `express` module from the `@nestjs/platform-express` package and the join function from the path module.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  // Add the following code
  app.use('/static', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

5. In the code above, we're telling the application to serve static files from the public folder when the URL starts with `/static`. You can change the `/static` part to any URL prefix you desire.
6. You can access your public images using the URL pattern: http://localhost:3000/static/image.jpg

Comment: I'll point out that if you have a static route `@Get(*)` then this will work fine setting `/` instead of `/static` if your goal was to serve static if present and fallback to wildcard if not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use express static module in nest js too.

```
// ...imports
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  
    // serve static assets from the client/dist folder, change this to the correct path for your project
    app.use(express.static(join(process.cwd(), '../client/dist/')));
  
    //... you config

   await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
 }
bootstrap();
```

Credit to : https://whatthecode.dev/serve-static-files-with-nest-js/