# how to get serve static images Nestjs

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs

I have been reading and implementing so many solutions but nothing seems to work.

I am using nestjs ServeStatic for their official doc and following question from StackOverflow.

but nothing seems to work.

So far my Code

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static/dist/serve-static.module';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [ 
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

**My Folder Structure**

```
/Source
  |-public
  |--img.jpg
  |-src
  |--app.module.ts
  |--app.controller.ts
  |--main.ts
```

**Trying to access the file through**

```
http://localhost:3000/public/img.jpg
```

**Error:**

```
[Nest] 3320   - 06/17/2021, 5:24:42 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'F:\code\dist\public\index.html' +3898ms
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'F:\code\dist\public\index.html'
```

**The Question I have been following**

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429380/how-to-serve-static-images-in-nestjs)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325062/how-to-serve-static-html-files-in-nest-js)

[Doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that it was looking for the file in **dist** folder. to resolve we have to get one level up and after that, it was getting the only index.html so for that we have to add **serveRoot**

**Code**

```
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static/dist/serve-static.module';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [ 
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '../public'), // added ../ to get one folder back
      serveRoot: '/public/' //last slash was important
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Comment: for me it also works without the ../ in the rootPath. ServeRoot needed, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You'r probably missing the prefix option in your `main.ts`.

```js
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {
  prefix: '/public',
});
```

You don't need to use the `ServeStaticModule` in your `app.module.ts`.

```js
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
    rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    // serveRoot: 'public'
}),
```

You can also remove this from your `main.ts`.

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.use('/', express.static('../public'));
```